# Is it possible to extract node locations from a STL file?

Tags: stl

I have 3D scanned wheel geometries of deformed tyres in an STL file format, and I would like to be able to do geometric analysis on them. One way I am familiar with is using the node locations to extract the information I am looking for.

I however cannot find a way to do this. If there is a program which can be used to analyse the geometry of STL files that would also be useful.